# See call stack while debugging in Pydev

Tags: python, debugging, pydev, callstack

Is there a way to see the call stack while debugging python in Pydev?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the "**Debug**" view of the "*Debug*" perspective :

[image]

You can see that I was inside a `failUnlessEqual` method, called by `test_01a`, called by a `new_method`...

Answer (score 1):

To have the complete stacktrace you could add the following watch expression:

```
[stackLine for stackLine in __import__("traceback").format_stack() if not 'pydev' in stackLine]
```

I am not sure if there is a better way to have the **complete** stacktrace...

Comment: Where would one add this ?